# stl map key find error

Tags: c++

This is my following code to extract the key and store it in the map

```
char * getData(char * str,char * pattern)
    {
      char *strTemp = new char[strlen(str)];
      strcpy(strTemp,str);
      char *ExtratedPatternData= (char *) NULL;
      int i=0;
      int LoopCount;

      ExtratedPatternData=strtok(strTemp," ");

      while(ExtratedPatternData)
        {
          if(strcmp(ExtratedPatternData,pattern) == 0)
        {
          ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL," ");
          LoopCount=atoi(ExtratedPatternData);

          for(i=0;i<LoopCount;i++)
            {
              if(ExtratedPatternData[2] == '\'')
            ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL,"'");       
              else
            ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL," ");         
            }
          delete strTemp;
          return ExtratedPatternData;
        }

          ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL," ");
          LoopCount=atoi(ExtratedPatternData)+1;

          for(i=0;i<LoopCount;i++)
        {
          if(ExtratedPatternData[2] == '\'')
            ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL,"'");       
          else
            ExtratedPatternData=strtok(NULL," ");         
        }
        }
      delete strTemp;  
      return "nill";
    }  

int main()
    {
      char * Instr;
      char * Key;
       FILE *pInFile;
      size_t len = 0;
     int Cntr=0;
           pInFile = fopen ("file.txt", "r");

        map<char *,int> History;

     while((getline (&Instr, &len , pInFile )!=-1))
       {
         Key=getData(Instr,"54001");

         if(History.count(Key))
           {
             cout<<History.find(Key)->second<<endl;
           }
         else
           {

         History[Key]=Cntr++;
           }
fclose(pInFile);
    return 0;
    }
```

In the above i am trying to read the contents of the file line by line.And based on the text "KEY" i am extracting the data and storing it in my MAP.
if(History.count(Key)) will always return 0 for the matched pattern.But if if return "nill" from "getData" function it is working fine.How to overcome this?

Comment: now that a lot of code. C oriented, no less.

Comment: @DavidHaim `new` `delete`  is a clear indicator for c++ code.

Comment: I didn't say it's a C code, I said it's C oriented code, meaning it does many stuff with C instead of C++, like using const char* and strcmp instead of std::string etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is most likely that you are using *pointers* for the keys. This will make the actual pointer the key, not the string they point to. If you want to use strings as keys, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that you're using pointers for keys, and `map` compares elements with `std::less` (i.e. `<`) by default.

There's also the problems of `strTemp` being one character too short, and of `getData` returning a dangling pointer, and the `delete`s that should be `delete[]` - all of which will cause undefined behaviour.

If you desperately want to use C strings, you need to define your own comparison for the map:

```
bool less_string(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)
{
    return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
}

// ...

map<char *, int, less_string> History;
```

You also need to fix the dangling pointer problem, of course. And the memory overrun.

A much better fix is to use `std::string` and its members in place of the C "string" library, though.
There's usually no need to write programs like it's 1969.